# How to update labels in Chart js?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, charts

I am using Chart.js in Angular. When I choose a date in a web app calendar, rest service sends response, chart is updated, x and y axis. On my x axis I have dates as strings. However, if my response has less data then before, (not every month has same number of days or not every response has equal number of data), x axis doesnt shrink.

This:

```
this.barChartLabels = this.xLabels;  //an array with many elements
if (selectedDateFormated === "2021-9-28") {
       this.barChartLabels = ["a","b","c","d"]; // overwrite for demo purpose
}
```

will give something like this:

[image]

It should be only a,b,c,d on x axis. How to do that?

I have this in my subscribe() method to delete previous data, before updating them again from rest api:

```
      this.barChartLabels = [];
      this.barChartData[0].data = [];
      this.barChartData[1].data = [];
      this.xLabels = [];
      this.Consumption = [];
      this.Flow = [];
      this.chart.update();
      this.resultSet.result.forEach(item => {
        this.xLabels.push(
          item.a
        );
        this.Flow.push(
          +item.b  //+ is casting string to number
        );
        this.Consumption.push(
          +item.f 
        );
      });
      this.barChartLabels = this.xLabels;
      this.barChartData[0].data = this.Consumption;
      this.barChartData[1].data = this.Flow;
```

Comment: You are left with previous data that exceed the new data because your array storing that data is Global. You should reset the data to an empty array before overwriting it. It will prevent this behaviour and also prevent memory leak in your app.

Comment: Ok, how to succesfully reset data? I edited my question so you can see how I reset my data. What am I doint wrong? Why is storing that data global?

Comment: Well i'm going to guess that the extra data reside in your resultSet.

You use this so you refer to this instance. and you start with an empty array. Then you push the result in. You should maybe console.log() your data to see what excatly your pushing in and if there is anything present before you push something in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 this.chart.chart.config.data.labels = this.xLabels;
```

This above did the trick.
And the chart is a reference to a chart in a view:

```
@ViewChild(BaseChartDirective, { static: true }) chart: BaseChartDirective;
```

Don't know what `this.chart.chart.config` it actualy does and why. It's something about a bug in ng2-charts.. So I made this two methods and called them at the end of subscribe() method when response from api is pushed in my arrays.

```
   refresh_chart() {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log("xLabels: " + this.xLabels);
            console.log("Consumption: " + this.consumption);
            if (this.chart && this.chart.chart && this.chart.chart.config) {
                this.chart.chart.config.data.labels = this.xLabels;
                this.chart.chart.config.data.datasets[0].data = this.consumption;
                this.chart.chart.update();
            }
        });
      }
    
      clearCharts() {
        this.barChartLabels= [];
        this.emptyChartData(this.barChartData);
      }
      emptyChartData(obj) {
         obj[0].data = [];
         obj[1].data = [];
      }
```